# Why won't a curved line through the origin be a subspace in 2D?

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand that any line through the origin is a subspace of a vector space. Why won't a curved line through the origin be a subspace in 2D?

When I think of a line through the origin, I think of a position vector. You can scale up or down that position vector, and add that position vector to another position vector to get a new vector still on that line through the origin. When we talk subspaces, are we talking only about position vectors? Or since I can move that position vector off the origin and its the same vector without changing its orientation, does that still count as a vector in the subspace?

So for a curved line through the origin (like a concave up or down thing), I can draw a position vector so that its tip touches the curve line. However, the base of the vector is at the origin, and not all of the vector lines along the curved line. Only the base and tip touch the curved line. Is this a vector in the subspace?

Comment: How have you had a subspace defined?

Comment: A curve will be a *subset*, but a *subspace* is a very special kind of subset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although being a *subset* of the 2D space, a curved line is not a *vector subspace* because it's not closed under ["the same vector space operations"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_subspace) of the ambient 2D.

But it would be a *vector space* of the points on the curve if we defined the addition and scalar multiplication opearting on arclengths along the curve.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple actually subspace are expected to be close under the operation /+ so if we add two points on the line we get another point on that line for instance on $y=x$ $ (1,1)+(3,3)=(4,4)$
Which is obviously not the case for curved lines